# Remove all files and folder in php including file in use

Tags: php, file

I am using function below, worked but sometimes some files are not being deleted  (for example json files) , the files may be in use in other applications

how can I improve the deletion process to make sure to delete all files and parent folder

```
private function removeDir($dir) {
    if (!file_exists($dir))
        return true;

    if (!is_dir($dir))
        return unlink($dir);

    foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
        if ($item == '.' || $item == '..')
            continue;

        if (is_file($item))
            return false;

        if (!$this->removeDir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item))
            return false;
    }

    if ($rm = rmdir($dir))
        $this->logSuccess("Removed dir");
    else
        $this->logError("Could not delete folder: ");


    return $rm;
}
```

Comment: If the file is in use by another application you have to kill that application,  the command line command `fuser file_name` would tell you which application that is.

Comment: how can I know if specific file in use?  I can not  kill other process, it's too dangarous .  is it possible to kill process for specific file?

Comment: `unlink` will only return false if it fails, fistly you should use `is_writable($dir)` check if you have permission to delete a file (and you also need write permission on the containing folder as well AFAIK) if you do and the delete still fails then check `fuser file_name` and see if it's in use. Needless to say, killing system processes and important files is dangerous.